# INNER JOIN is extremly slow on some rows and create temp table

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, entity-framework, temporary-tables

The MySQL query

```
SELECT `p`.*,
       `p.Author`.*
FROM   `post` AS `p`
       INNER JOIN `user` AS `p.Author` ON `p`.`userid` = `p.Author`.`userid`
WHERE  ( ( `p`.`threadid` = 29780 )
         AND ( `p`.`parentid` <> 0 ) )
       AND `p`.`visible` IN ( 1, 2 )
ORDER  BY `p`.`dateline`,
          `p`.`postid`
LIMIT  10 offset 0
```

takes about ~800ms to 1000ms and create a temp table with all rows in `user` table (about 17k)

[image: explain result]

Strangely this doesn't appear on other threads. Lets change the `threadid` filter to 2978**1**

[image]

On `threadid = 29781` the PK is used as expected. So this query is **much** faster and took only about 0.000056ms on my testserver where `threadid = 29780` ran for nearly a second. Can't explain why the first case creates a temp table: `user.userid` is PK.

Tested on MariaDB 10.2 and 10.3 running on Docker.

**Edit**

Can break it down to this query:

```
select post.*, user.*
from post
inner join user on user.userid=post.userid
where threadid=29780
order by post.dateline
limit 10
```

**Edit #2**

Tried to force using the index

```
select post.*, user.*
from post use index(PRIMARY)
inner join user use index(PRIMARY) on user.userid=post.userid 
where threadid=29780
order by post.dateline
limit 10
```

The index on `post` make it faster, but still slow for sql (~100ms). `EXPLAIN` say that no key on `post` table is used, so the whole table (~350k rows) is scanned. Forcing the index on `user` doesn't seem to have any effect.

The `ORDER BY` seems to be the problem. When removing it, execution speed is fine. Altough it seems that `dateline` has an index. Ordering by `postid` (PK) also takes very long.

### Background

I'm using Entity Framework core to query an existing vBulletin database. The query above is part of a EF generated query, which should fetch the replys of a thread. In the tests I found the query to one test thread extremly slow. So I break it down to the query above.

Here the table definitions:

#### post

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
    `postid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `threadid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `parentid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `userid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `title` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `dateline` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pagetext` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `allowsmilie` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showsignature` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ipaddress` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `iconid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `visible` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `attach` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `infraction` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reportthreadid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `post_thanks_amount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `htmlstate` ENUM('off','on','on_nl2br') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on_nl2br',
    `isForeign` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`postid`),
    INDEX `threadid` (`threadid`, `userid`),
    INDEX `threadid_visible_dateline` (`threadid`, `visible`, `dateline`, `userid`, `postid`),
    INDEX `ipaddress` (`ipaddress`),
    INDEX `dateline` (`dateline`),
    INDEX `userid` (`userid`, `parentid`),
    INDEX `user_date` (`userid`, `dateline`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

#### user

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `userid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `usergroupid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `membergroupids` CHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `displaygroupid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `password` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `passworddate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01',
    `email` CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `styleid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `parentemail` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `homepage` CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `icq` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `aim` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `yahoo` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `msn` CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `skype` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `showvbcode` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showbirthday` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
    `usertitle` CHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `customtitle` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `joindate` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `daysprune` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastvisit` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastactivity` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastpost` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastpostid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `posts` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reputation` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
    `reputationlevelid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `timezoneoffset` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `pmpopup` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `avatarid` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `avatarrevision` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `profilepicrevision` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sigpicrevision` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `options` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '33570831',
    `birthday` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `birthday_search` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01',
    `maxposts` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `startofweek` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `ipaddress` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `referrerid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `languageid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `emailstamp` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `threadedmode` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `autosubscribe` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
    `pmtotal` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pmunread` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `salt` CHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ipoints` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `infractions` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `warnings` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `infractiongroupids` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `infractiongroupid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `adminoptions` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `profilevisits` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `friendcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `friendreqcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vmunreadcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vmmoderatedcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `socgroupinvitecount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `socgroupreqcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pcunreadcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pcmoderatedcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gmmoderatedcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `post_thanks_user_amount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `post_thanks_thanked_posts` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `post_thanks_thanked_times` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `xperience_done` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_level` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `xperience_levelp` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `xperience_next_level` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_next_level_points` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `xperience_ppd` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_awards` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `xperience_shopitems` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `xperience_achievements` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `xperience_lastupdate` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_awardcount` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_promotioncount` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `xperience_achievementcount` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ncode_imageresizer_mode` ENUM('none','enlarge','samewindow','newwindow') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ncode_imageresizer_maxwidth` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ncode_imageresizer_maxheight` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vbseo_likes_in` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vbseo_likes_out` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vbseo_likes_unread` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `itrader_total` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `itrader_pcnt` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `itrader_buy` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `itrader_sell` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `assetposthash` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `fbuserid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `fbjoindate` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fbname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `logintype` ENUM('vb','fb') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'vb',
    `fbaccesstoken` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `newrepcount` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `bloggroupreqcount` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showblogcss` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `vsafrules_date` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vsafrules_sets` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `showvsastats` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `ars_count` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `indexpage` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `isForeign` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stylechoosen` INT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `recent_thankcnt` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `recent_thankact` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `uloShowDesktopNotifications` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `source` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
    INDEX `usergroupid` (`usergroupid`),
    INDEX `username` (`username`),
    INDEX `birthday` (`birthday`, `showbirthday`),
    INDEX `birthday_search` (`birthday_search`),
    INDEX `referrerid` (`referrerid`),
    INDEX `post_thanks_thanked_times` (`post_thanks_thanked_times`),
    INDEX `fbuserid` (`fbuserid`),
    INDEX `email` (`email`),
    INDEX `lastactivity` (`lastactivity`),
    INDEX `post_thanks_thanked_times_2` (`post_thanks_thanked_times`),
    INDEX `itrader_total` (`itrader_total`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this

```
    WHERE  `p`.`threadid` = 29780
      AND  `p`.`parentid` <> 0
      AND  `p`.`visible` IN ( 1, 2 )
```

The following index is optimal:

```
INDEX(threadid, visible)
```

Tacking more columns onto it (which you have done) probably does not help.

No index can finish off the `WHERE` clause *and* get into the `ORDER BY` because of the `<>`.  So you are stuck with a sort and the temp table that goes with it.  Furthermore, since you cannot make a single `INDEX` to handle both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`, you can't get to the `LIMIT` in time to prevent fetching possibly lots of rows.

Even if you got rid of `p.parentid <> 0`, the `IN` would prevent having a single index to do the task.

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` might be a solution.  This should force it to reference `p` first.

This is terribly confusing: p.Author means database p, table Author. Yet you seem to have a table named p.Author?!

Don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.

Don't use `CHAR` except for truely constant-sized columns; use `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

`user` table should have both the multicolumn indexes by the `(id, userid)` and `(userid, id)` columns while `post` table should have the index `(postid, threadid, parentid, userid, visible, dateline)` The order columns appear in the latter index also can be changed but I estimate an affordable result with the proposed one.

Also my advice is to migrate to the InnoDB from the MyISAM engine that will become obsolete soon.

Comment: What column do you mean by `id`? The `user` table has only a single id column called `userid` which is the PK. It seems that it has something to do with `ORDER BY`. When removing it, the small test query is pretty fast. Ordering by `post.postid` is also slow, where `user.userid` is fast...